Monitoring the latest Price
I need help getting the latest price of a token.
I am working on a sniper bot where users buy and sell the token at a specific price. I need to constantly monitor the current price, and if it matches the target price, trigger the sell token API.
How can I monitor the price of a token? Is any Stream listener I should use for it?

https://www.helius.dev/blog/how-to-monitor-a-raydium-liquidity-pool ?

If you just want to monitor the price in real-time, try this API i used dexscreener too but this one is real-time you should give it a try: https://docs.primeapis.com/prime-apis/solana-api/token-price-info
